# Manipulate table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am stuck working with a horrible application that has table driven layout.  It is severely limiting and I can not add unique classes or really do anything to edit the html output.  Can someone show me how I could possibly manipulate the layout using jQuery.

The code looks something like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <TABLE CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="" BORDER="0">
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                    <TABLE CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0">
                        <TR>
                            <TD STYLE="padding:3px;">
                                <TABLE CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0">
                                <TD NOWRAP CLASS="MainNavigation">
                                Link 1</TD>
                                </TABLE>
                            </TD>
                            <TD STYLE="padding:3px;">
                                <TABLE CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0">
                                <TD NOWRAP CLASS="MainNavigation">
                                Link 2</TD>
                                </TABLE>
                            </TD>
                            <TD STYLE="padding:3px;">
                                <TABLE CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0">
                                <TD NOWRAP CLASS="MainNavigation">
                                Link 3</TD>
                                </TABLE>
                            </TD>
                        </TR>
                    </TABLE>

                    <TABLE CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0" >
                        <TR>
                            <TD STYLE="padding:3px;">
                                <TABLE CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0">
                                <TD NOWRAP CLASS="MainNavigation">
                                Link 4</TD>
                                </TABLE>
                            </TD>
                            <TD STYLE="padding:3px;">
                                <TABLE CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0">
                                <TD NOWRAP CLASS="MainNavigation">
                                Link 5</TD>
                                </TABLE>
                            </TD>
                        </TR>
                    </TABLE>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ugly right?!

So from this example how could I manipulate it with scripts to move Link 3 into the second table?  I started a fiddle with this here :

http://jsfiddle.net/2gYfq/

Comment: does anything have a class or an ID to select from?

Comment: Wow, that's not only ugly it's also invalid (there's several `td` elements as the direct child of a `table` element). May I suggest moving to a different application? ...I know that it's not easy to do that within a corporation, but it might well be worth the effort in reduced development costs.

Comment: @David.. heh I wish.. but no way.  People here have spent months working with this crappy thing.. it is amazing to me as it was developed by a huge (multi-billion?) dollar company.. you would think they could update their code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucky for us, jQuery has ways to easily deal with such ugliness.  Using [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/), and [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) you can:

```
var refTD = $('.MainNavigation:contains("Link 4")').parent().closest('td');
$('.MainNavigation:contains("Link 3")').parent().closest('td')
                                       .detach()
                                       .insertBefore(refTD);
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fcm7r/3/)